# Why matplotlib starts to draw barchart instead of line chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, linechart

This simple code draws line chart as expected:

```
james_f=names[(names.name=='James') & (names.sex=='F')]
plt.plot(james_f['year'],james_f['births'])    
plt.show()
```

[image]

But then I change condition, just delete one of them, and then it starts to draw bar chart. Why and how to force to draw line chart?

```
james_f=names[(names.name=='James')]
plt.plot(james_f['year'],james_f['births'])    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Adding instead of it 1==1 rule, nothing changes(

```
james_f=names[(names.name=='James') & ( 1 == 1)]
plt.plot(james_f['year'],james_f['births'])    
plt.show()
```

Even this code draws barchart:

```
james_f=names[(names.name=='James') | (names.name=='John') | (names.name=='Robert') ]
plt.plot(james_f['year'],james_f['births'])
```

`james_f['births']` output (pandas.core.series.Series):

```
228           46
343           22
538           11
942         9655
944         5927
2312          26
2329          24
2617           9
2938        8769
....
Name: births, dtype: int64
```

`james_f['births'].min()` return 7 There is no zero or NaN values

```
>>> print(james_f[james_f['births'].isnull()])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, sex, births, year]
Index: []


>>> james_f.head(10)
        name    sex births  year
343     James   F   22      1880
944     James   M   5927    1880
2329    James   F   24      1881
2940    James   M   5441    1881
4372    James   F   18      1882
4965    James   M   5892    1882
6428    James   F   25      1883
7118    James   M   5223    1883
8488    James   F   33      1884
9320    James   M   5693    1884
```

Comment: It looks like you have some zeroes in your data rather than matplotlib changing its behaviour. What's the output of `james_f['births']` in the problematic case?

Comment: What's the output of `james_f['births']`?

Comment: @TillHoffmann updated info

Comment: Thanks for the updated information. Seems to all look good. Are you able to share the original data? Zooming in on, for example, the 1880 to 1900 range may reveal more of what's going on with the data.

Comment: I see! Not filtering on the gender gives you two observations for each year: one for male, one for female. Hence the line plot oscillates heavily making it appear as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not filtering on gender yields two observations per year: one for women and one for men. The numbers of men and women with name 'James' are vastly different making the plot appear very noisy. You have (at least) two options:

(1) Sum up the number of men and women like so.

```
james = names[names.name == 'james']
years = []
births = []
for year, subset in james.groupby('year'):
    years.append(year)
    births.append(subset.births.sum())

plt.plot(years, births)
```

Someone with more pandas skills can probably write this as one line.

(2) Plot two separate lines for men and women like so.

```
james = names[names.name == 'james']
for sex, subset in james.groupby('sex'):
    plt.plot(subset.year, subset.births, label=sex)
plt.legend()
```